# Java - Merging two sets of code

Tags: java, arrays, regex, list

I've written two separate pieces of code. Now I want to merge both pieces of code. Now one part opens a text file and displays the contents of the text file and the second piece of code validates manually entered postcodes. Now I want to read a text file and then automatically validate postcodes within the text file. Not sure how I can merge them. Any questions please ask as I'm stuck.

```
package postcodesort;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class PostCodeSort 
{
  Queue<String> postcodeStack = new LinkedList<String>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {
    FileReader fileReader = null;

    // Create the FileReader object
    try {
      fileReader = new FileReader("postcodes1.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      String str;

      while((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
      {
        System.out.println(str + "");
      }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
      // handle exception;
    } 
    finally 
    {
      fileReader.close();
    }

    // Close the input
  }
}
```

Second part that manually validates postcodes:

```
List<String> zips = new ArrayList<String>();

//Valid ZIP codes
zips.add("SW1W 0NY"); 
zips.add("PO16 7GZ"); 
zips.add("GU16 7HF"); 
zips.add("L1 8JQ"); 

//Invalid ZIP codes
zips.add("Z1A 0B1");
zips.add("A1A 0B11");

String regex = "^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String zip : zips)
{
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(zip);
  System.out.println(matcher.matches());
}
```

Comment: Try being more specific with the question and explain the context of the problem you are facing, so that other can address your issue.

Comment: I also find lot of unnecessary code in your snippet. like `String inputFileName = "postcodes1.txt";` if you are directly giving the file name what is the use of the above statement?

Comment: what do you have in the file? Is it having the zip codes that you have in the second snippet?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. Are these 2 pieces of code in 2 separate classes or just 1? Are they in the same package?

Comment: Merging should not be your goal, extract the second snippet into a ZipCodeValidator class.

Comment: Sounds like you need 2 classes here. Read the arraylist from the first class, and pass it as a parameter in an argument to a method in the second class.

Comment: So ultimately I want a program that can both read a text file e.g. "postcodes1.txt" and then validate the postcodes within the text file and print them.

Comment: So the first snippet of code is simply reading a text file with a bunch of postcodes in it and then displaying them. I want to read the text file and then validate the postcodes like the second snippet of code is doing. Hence my idea for merging them which seems is not very popular here so how do I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class called something like ZipCodeValidator that contains the functionality of your second snippet. It will look something like this

```
public class ZipCodeValidator {
    private static String regex = "^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$";
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    public boolean isValid(String zipCode) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(zip);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of this class

```
ZipCodeValidator zipCodeValidator = new ZipCodeValidator();
```

and then use it in your main method

```
boolean valid = zipCodeValidator.isValid(zipCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging your question and the answer by @hiflyer I posted this answer, this makes an assumption that the file `postcodes1.txt` has all the zip codes in separate lines.

```
   package postcodesort;


    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Queue;
    import java.util.TreeSet;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;


    public class PostCodeSort 
    {
        Queue<String> postcodeStack = new LinkedList<String>();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            FileReader fileReader = null;
            ZipCodeValidator zipCodeValidator = new ZipCodeValidator();

            // Create the FileReader object
            try {
                fileReader = new FileReader("postcodes1.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                String str;
                while((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    if(zipCodeValidator.isValid(str)){
                        System.out.println(str + " is valid");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(str + " is not valid");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                // handle exception;
            }

            finally 
            {
                fileReader.close();
            }

        }
    }

    public class ZipCodeValidator {
        private static String regex = "^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$";
        private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        public boolean isValid(String zipCode) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(zip);
            return matcher.matches();
        }
    }
```